# Gulp sourcemaps module not creating file, no errors

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

I am working on a gulp workflow, and have just piped `gulp-sourcemaps` to my pipeline. However it id not creating a sourmapfile as it should. I freely admint that the i am confused by the folder destination parameter. I would like the sourcemap to be in the same folder as my css file, unless there is good reason for not doing that.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gulp-intro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple Gulp introduction",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4"
  }
}
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
/**
 * = Gulp specific dependencies
 */
const gulp          = require('gulp');
const rename        = require('gulp-rename');

/**
 * = CSS Style task
 */
const sass          = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


const styleSrc      = './src/scss/style.scss';
const styleDist     = './assets/css/';

gulp.task('style', () => {
    gulp.src(styleSrc)
        .pipe(sass({
            errorLogToConsole: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(styleDist));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a silly mistake, but i forgot to initialize gulp-sourcemaps at the beginning of my gulp task using sourcemaps.init().

**Example:**

```
gulp.task('style', () => {
    gulp.src(styleSrc)

        // Initialize sourcemaps  
   ===> .pipe(sourcemaps.init() <===

        .pipe(sass({
            errorLogToConsole: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(styleDist));
});
```